# why I need web-server to load angular webapp

Tags: angular, production

I put my angular webapp into production and reading the official documentation I realized that I need a web server, is it so? In this case when I upload my online webapp we will need to specify the port in the url? for example www.mywebapp.com:4200 If not, how does it work? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you will need a server to host and serve the files. No, you don't need to set the port, because you will serve from your servers public folder (most likely) and on the default port for HTTP, port 80, or the default HTTPS port 443 in case you have an SSL certificate that you will use.

Comment: What happens if there are more than one web app in the server?

Comment: They should live in separate folders and be accessible from different server routes (URL's)

Comment: ok I understand, thanks for your replyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of confusion here. I'll explain as better as I can.

When you are serving the app with command `ng serve` you are about to run a web-server locally made in nodeJS. By default it run on port `4200` but you can change it by using a flag: `ng serve --port 4567`. By doing this you wont reach your site if you type `localhost:4200` in the browser, but you need to use the `4567` port.

> The reason why by default the port is 4200 is because most likely
>   there aren't other applications using that port.

When you build your application the result is a `dist` folder, that contain a list of files. All those files can be interpreted by the browser, while the `*.ts` doesn't.

Since Typescript is a `superset` of Javascript it needs to be compiled. That what the build does, mainly. So now you have this list of files ready to be deployed. Here comes the question you asked, `do I need a web server?`

> It depends.

If the application doesn't need to go online and doesn't do any http calls at all or interact with a backend / db you can simply open the `index.html` directly on your browser and it will works fine. Hence no need to use a `web-server`.

If this is not your case, then you need a web-server. The reason is simple, every site is hosted on a server. A machine with a public IP that can be resolved everywhere (excluding cases when the national ISP (internet service provider) cut the connection at the beginning).

Let's take SO as an example. If you type, in the browser, `www.stackoverflow.com` you will reach the site. If you type `www.stackoverflow.com:80` you will get the same result.

Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

if you scroll down a bit you will see that the port `80` is used for `HTTP requests`. That's the standard, and all the browsers by default, when you try to navigate to a site, will use this port (for HTTPS requests the port change to `443`, but the logic is kinda the same).

You could also configure your server's firewall to NOT accept any connections on port 80 but on port `12443`, and put a web-server that is listening on that port. The result will be that if you type `www.mysite.com` the browser will give you the classic error "Cannot reach www.mysite.com". But if you type `mysite.com:12443` you will get the wanted result. In this case, the dist folder's content.

> You also asked: What happens if there are more than one web app in the
>   server?

You have two choice, to me:

1) Every web server use different ports. You can then navigate to your specific content using different ports on requests:

```
www.mysite.com -> standard site on port 80.
www.mysite.com:456 -> another site on port 456
and so on...
```

2) Use a `reverse-proxy` to handle all the different requests on a specified port (by default, 80 and 443 | HTTP and HTTPS).

This topic is really complex but let's take this as an example.
You have three different sites that you want to host on your server.

You *could* use `docker` with `nginx` (nginx is a webserver, like IIS or apache) and `nginx-proxy` to setup the perfect scenario.
I'll post some code that I personally use on my VPS if someone is interessed.

I've a `Dockerfile` to build the main container:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./site/ /usr/share/nginx/site_volume
COPY ./static/ /usr/share/nginx/assets_volume
COPY ./site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

The nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/site_volume;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.com

    root /usr/share/nginx/site_volume;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  static.mysite.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/assets_volume;
}
```

The result, after building and running the container:

```
docker build -t my-site .
docker run -d -p 80:80 my-site
```

is that when I navigate to `mysite.com` or `www.mysite.com` I will see something. If I navigate to `static.mysite.com` I will see something else, not related to the content on the first two navigations.

> EDIT, if someone is interessed on how to run those containers with an HTTPS
>   redirect I can add some code with some details.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you would need a **service** to host your web application, not necessarily a web server these days.

### Hosting

#### Web Server

When you choose to use a web server, it could either be a **dedicated** server or a **shared** server. You would use a **dedicated** server when you expect a large amount of traffic consuming high amount of server CPU and memory usage.

If you are hosting a staging or demo site, you could use a **shared** service, where multiple hosted sites/web apps use the same server/IP address. By making use of [Virtual Hosts](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/V/virtual_host.html), the server can determine for which domain the request is (e.g. my-webapp.com) and displaying the correct web app. This is not easy to configure, but there are many services out there that make it very easy to host multiple web apps from one server. One example is [Runcloud](https://runcloud.io).

#### Static Hosting

Alternatively you can host your web app from cloud storage services like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Microsoft Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/storage/search/). This is also great for leveraging the benefits of CDN services.

#### Heroku (and/or others)

You can also make use of a service like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) to manage and host your web application. Here is a post to get started with [Angular and Heroku](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352).

## Building

Before you *deploy* your web app to either of these or other solutions, you have to build/prepare your app by using the Angular CLI's [Build](https://angular.io/cli/build) process. Be sure to have a look at the Angular documentation on [Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages) and pay attention to URL rewriting (for web servers) or fallback requirements for static hosting.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of compilation (building) your Angular application you are getting static files (html, css, js) and those files need to be hosted and served, this will allow other to use/consume this. Some (not all) popular choice here could be Nginx or Apache or server less solution like Heroku or Amazon etc.